# Why did my app update get rejected from Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

I received the following rejection reason.

> Thanks for contacting the Google Play team about your app Company
>   App name, com.company.app. We reviewed your app
>   and found that it does not qualify for use of the requested
>   permissions.
>
> The declared functionality Select OEM Services  is determined to be
>   unnecessary or not aligned with the core functionality of your app.

What permission are they referring to ?

Below are the permissions I'm requesting.

> com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT,
>   com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE,
>   com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE,
>   com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES,
>   com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS,
>   com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT,
>   com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE,
>   com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ,
>   com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE,
>   com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE
>   android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
>   android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,
>   android.permission.AUDIO_INPUT_FLAG_FAST,
>   android.permission.BLUETOOTH,
>   android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
>   android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY,
>   android.permission.CAMERA,
>   android.permission.FLASHLIGHT,
>   android.permission.INTERNET,
>   android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS,
>   android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
>   android.permission.READ_LOGS, 
>   android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
>   android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, 
>   android.permission.USE_SIP,
>   android.permission.VIBRATE, 
>   android.permission.WAKE_LOCK,
>   android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
>   android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS

Comment: one way is to check it in your manifest (which permissions and features you declare) or in your Google Play Console under the app's release description there is a list of permissions and features app is using

Comment: @Rainmaker Yes, first thing I checked but could not see anything referring to "Select OEM services"

Comment: do you have any aar files added to your project as dependencies? those also have manifests and may contain OEM related permissions

Comment: @Rainmaker I do but I'm pretty sure those get merged into the main manifest.

Comment: they do, that's the point, the permissions you don't see in your main manifest could be reflected in the console under the release apk description, so you should check that IMHO

Answer (score 1):

Most likely culprit is this one: `android.permission.READ_LOGS`

Reason is because of:

> Allows an application to read the low-level system log files.
>
> Not for use by third-party applications, because Log entries can contain the user's private information.
>
> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_LOGS

It's not allowed for third-party apps.